# how to redirect to correct controller action method

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view that is been used in several places in the product. Within this view, I am doing a JSON call via `Url.Action(“MyActionMethod  ”,10)` that calls this method MyActionMethod  from Home controller. My problem is when I use this partial view from a different place (let’s say MyView1 in context of AccountController ), its trying to search for Account/MyActionMethod whereas this method is available at Home/MyActionMethod . If I change code to  `Url.Action("/Home/MyActionMethod" ,10)`, it basically looks for Account/Home/MyActionMethod .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Url.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController")
```

or if you are using areas and you want to specify the root:

```
Url.Action("MyActionMethod", "MyController", new { area = "" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct overload.

`Url.Action("actioname","controllername",new {id:10})`